# Would JSR-330 (Inject) replace the managed-bean in JSR-314 (JSF) in future?

Tags: java

I think the two are overlapped in some way, which make confusion to beginners. This maybe a bad question, but I don't know where to ask. As both are using Java annotations (@ManagedBean and @Inject), will they become one at last? Also, see the raising of .Net framework, Microsoft seems always moving forward faster..

Comment: .Net is AFAIK way behind if it comes to dependency injection.

Comment: Probably a question for [Ed Burns](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) or another member of the expert group.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I read an interesting discussion about it: [JSF and CDI](http://old.nabble.com/JSF-and-CDi-td32140416.html) and [MyFaces CDI wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/JSF+Usage#JSFUsage-JSF2.0ScopeAnnotations) might be also interesting for you.